# How does Spring MVC @PathVariable receive parameters with multiple '/'?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, path-variables

I was working on a file upload widget for managing images.

I wish that image paths can be received via `@PathVariable` in Spring MVC, such as `http://localhost:8080/show/img/20181106/sample.jpg` instead of `http://localhost:8080/show?imagePath=/img/20181106/sample.jpg`.

But `/` will be resolved Spring MVC, and it will always return 404 when accessing.

Is there any good way around this?

Comment: you should use this format for `RequestMapping` `http://localhost:8080/show/{imagePath:.+}`

Comment: If there are multiple `/` in `imagePath`, this format still returns 404.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use like below.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/show/{path:.+}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public File getImage(@PathVariable String path) {
        // logic goes here
}
```

Here `.+` is a regexp match, it will not truncate .jpg in your path.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry to say that, but I think the answer of @Alien does not the answer the question : it only handle the case of a dot `.`  in the `@PathVariable` but not the case of slashes `/`.

I had the problem once and here is how I solved it, it's not very elegant but stil ok I think :

```
private AntPathMatcher antPathMatcher = new AntPathMatcher();

@GetMapping("/show/**")
public ... image(HttpServletRequest request) {
    String uri = (String) request.getAttribute(HandlerMapping.PATH_WITHIN_HANDLER_MAPPING_ATTRIBUTE);
    String pattern = (String) request.getAttribute(HandlerMapping.BEST_MATCHING_PATTERN_ATTRIBUTE);
    String path = antPathMatcher.extractPathWithinPattern(pattern, uri);

    ...
}
```